# Проблема со сдвигом массива структур

Tags: c++, список

При реализации функции вставки в голову блочного списка у меня возникает некорректная работа функции insertToHead. Она правильно сдвигает массив, но не правильно сдвигает поле char, в результате получается ситуация как на скрине.[image: неправильный перенос поля char].
~

```
struct Data
{
    char ch;
    int arr[10];
};

struct Node
{
    Data data[BLOCK_SIZE];
    Node* next = 0;
    Node*  prev = 0;
    int count = 0;
};

struct List
{
    Node* head = 0;
    Node* tail = 0;
};

void insertToHead(List* list, Data data) {
    if (list->head == 0) {
        Node* tmp = new Node;
        tmp->next = 0;
        tmp->tail = 0;
        tmp->count = 1;
        tmp->data[0] = data;
        list->head = tmp;
        list->tail = tmp;
    }
    else {
        if (list->head->count < BLOCK_SIZE) {
            for (int i = list->head->count; i > 0; --i) {
                list->head->data[i] = list->head->data[i - 1];
            }
            list->head->data[0] = data;
            list->head->count++;
        }
        else {
            Node* tmp = new Node;
            tmp->next = 0;
            tmp->tail = 0;
            tmp->count = 1;
            tmp->data[0] = data;
            tmp->next = list->head;
            list->head = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Буду благодарен, если вы укажете на мою ошибку в коде.

Comment: почему у вас `Node` имеет `tail`?

Comment: Это указатель на  блочного списка.

Comment: уточните в вопросе что за "блочный список" - мне не знакома такая структура данных

Comment: Простите, это должен быть указатель на предыдущий элемент, сейчас поправлю

Comment: Вот - http://lk.stu.lipetsk.ru/file/?datasource=ME_TEACHINGMATERIALS&field=DOC&typeoid=5:89014192&oid=5:96674906&filename=%CC%D3_1891_%F1%F2%F0%F3%EA%F2%F3%F0%FB_%E4%E0%ED%ED%FB%F5.pdf

Comment: так, а что означает: "Она правильно сдвигает массив, но не правильно сдвигает поле char"? Что сдесь не правильного и как правильно? уточните вопрос

Comment: При добавлении записи в голову приходится сдвигать массив на 1 позицию вправо, чтобы предоставить место для новых данных.

Comment: ну и... сдвигаете, что не так?

Comment: А то, что после добавления нового элемента все хранимые char-ы теряются (ситуация описана на скрине) .

Comment: где она описана? Если вам нужно определенное поведение, так опишите какое и чем оно отличается от нынешнего

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы программа корректно хранила генерируемые данные (рандомные). С массивами все в порядке.  А с char на деле выходит, что все хранимые поля  перекрываются новым добавляемым значением.